# How can I obtain the coordinates of a selected item container in a WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, coordinates, selecteditem

I want to display some WPF elements near to the selected item of a ListView. How can I obtain the coordinates (screen or relative) of the selected ListViewItem?

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="TechSchoolListView"
    ClipToBounds="False"
    Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
    VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
    ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TechSchoolDataTemplate}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TechSchoolResearchList, Mode=Default}" 
    SelectedIndex="1"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTechSchool, Mode=Default}" 
    SelectionChanged="TechSchoolList_SelectionChanged" 
    ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource TechSchoolItemContainerStyle}" 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
    <ListView.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource PanelBackgroundColor}"/>
    </ListView.Background>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ContainerFromElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346420.aspx) to get the item's container, which is a visual and from there you can get the coordinates. You can't express this in XAML, however. You need to do it in code, on one of the ListView events, raised when the selected item is changed. Btw, keep in mind that the item can be its own container.

You can't do this in XAML, as there's no attached property on the item that shows the item is selected. (though I haven't played with WPF in a while, so that might have changed)

Comment: Thank you, but I have to give an ItemsControl to the ContainerFromElement function. Where did I get the ItemsControl for the selected item?

Comment: ContainerFromElement() has two overloads. One of them is a static and needs the ItemsControl instance. The other one is instance method and takes only the Item.In your case it'll be like this: TechSchoolListView.ContainerFromElement(<selected item>).

Answer (score 3):

Now I have found a solution by myself. I have searched for a simple property, but it made no sense, because all UI Elements in the WPF are relative.

This code seems to be working:

```
        UIElement selectedContainer = (UIElement) TechSchoolListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(TechSchoolListView.SelectedIndex);
        Point cursorPos = selectedContainer.TranslatePoint(new Point(selectedContainer.DesiredSize.Width, 0.0), Page);
        PanelCursor.Height = selectedContainer.DesiredSize.Height;
        PanelCursor.Margin = new Thickness(400, cursorPos.Y, 0.0, 0.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Franci Penov's answer is correct I would like to give a code sample to show how what he was saying worked for me.

```
UIElement selectedContainer = (UIElement)(sender as 
ListView).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex((sender as 
ListView).SelectedIndex);
Point startPoint = selectedContainer.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0));
```